# How to define a recursive concept?

Tags: c++, recursion, c++20, c++-concepts

The [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) states that:

> Concepts cannot recursively refer to themselves

But how can we define a concept that will represent an integer or a vector of integers, or a vector of vector of integers, etc.

I can have something this:

```
template < typename Type > concept bool IInt0 = std::is_integral_v<Type>;
template < typename Type > concept bool IInt1 = IInt0<Type> || requires(Type tt) { {*std::begin(tt)} -> IInt0; };
template < typename Type > concept bool IInt2 = IInt1<Type> || requires(Type tt) { {*std::begin(tt)} -> IInt1; };

static_assert(IInt2<int>);
static_assert(IInt2<std::vector<int>>);
static_assert(IInt2<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>);
```

But I want to have something like `IIntX` that will mean IInt*N* for any N.

Is it possible?

Comment: I'm curious as to exactly what code you want to apply this concept to. How do you write code that can manipulate an integer and a vector in the same way, without using a bunch of `if constexpr` or equivalent code, which would ultimately make the whole point of the concept moot? Indeed, you should look very carefully on the use of `||` in a concept

Comment: @NicolBolas It is hard for `||` to support infinite nested containers.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I think the pointer is more... what is your algorithm that does something meaningful for both `int` and `vector<vector<vector<int>>>`?

Comment: @Barry That isn't hard?  I mean, "increment every int" is meaningful for both.  Auto-unboxing of monads (or operating on its content) isn't insanity, even if it requires arbitrary descent.  Auto-boxing *is* insanity in my opinion; the other way around, especially on a single operation, is fine.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: Perhaps a more reasonable use case would be a concept for a function that takes a range of ranges and flattens the range. Logically, such a things should be able to tunnel arbitrarily down the `value_type` of each inner range until it finds a non-range thing, with all of the various ranges having to agree on the same `value_type`. But there's no way to easily express that in a concept. Or at least, not without going to horrible, non-concept stuff.

Comment: This is just a simple example that I picked to illustrate the issue. The real-world problem that made me post this question is of-course another.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Concepts can always defer to a type trait:

```
template <typename T> concept C = some_trait<T>::value;
```

And that trait can be recursive:

```
template <typename T>
struct some_trait : std::false_type { };

template <std::Integral T>
struct some_trait<T> : std::true_type { };

template <typename T, typename A>
struct some_trait<std::vector<T, A>> : some_trait<T> { };
```

If you don't mean just `vector`, then the last partial specialization can be generalized to:

```
template <std::Range R>
struct some_trait<R> : some_trait<std::range_value_t<R>> { };
```