# Self-recursive concept

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I know concepts cannot be recursive. Still, I'd like a concept that "refers itself", such as

```
template<class T>
concept hasA = requires(const T& t, const "hasA"& u )
{
    { t.a(u) } -> std::same_as<bool>;
}
```

that is, a concept `hasA` describing some type declaring some member with prototype

```
template<hasA A> bool a(const A& a);
```

While [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56741456/how-to-define-a-recursive-concept) provides some insight, I don't see how I'm going to solve my problem without using good 'ol SFINAE hell... which is exactly why concepts were created in the first place.

Full snippet below

```
#include <concepts>

template<class T>
concept hasA = requires(const T& t)
{
    { t.a(t) } -> std::same_as<bool>;  
};

struct A
{
    template<hasA AA>
    bool a(const AA& a) const { return true; }  
}; 

struct B
{
    template<hasA AA>
    bool a(const AA& a) const { return false; }
}; 

template<hasA AA, hasA BB>
bool wrapper(const AA& a, const BB& b)
{
    return a.a(b);
}

int main()
{    
    A a; B b;
    wrapper(a, a); //should work (same types), but doesn't
    wrapper(a, b); //doesn't work (different types), but I'd like to
    wrapper(b, a); //doesn't work (different types), but I'd like to
    wrapper(b, b); //should work (same types), but doesn't
}
```

Comment: "*I'd like a concept that "refers itself"*" What is that supposed to mean? No, really, what does `hasA` actually *mean*? If you define a thing in terms of itself, you haven't actually defined it. This is why proper recursive calls always have a terminating condition, a set of parameters that is a definitive, non-self-referential value. What is that non-self-referential condition for your `hasA` concept?

Comment: It's not about recursion, it wouldn't work even with two different concepts. Concepts can't magically check if something compiles for some category of types.

Comment: `hasA` describes a type declaring some member with prototype `bool a(const T& a);`, where `T` is submitted under the same constraint. I write what I expect to work in the full snippet. I don't want it to work for some other arbitrary class `C` not declaring such a member function.